# Flight time has been changed - Ryanair refuses to cancel

Tags: air-travel, eu, cancellations, ryanair

I have received today an email that my flight time has been changed from 10:50 to 12:15. Even if it is 1 hour and 25 minutes I wanted to cancel my flight (Flight is only about 1 hour). The airline (in this case Ryanair)  gave me only two options:

1. Confirm the change that is made by them.
2. I can reschedule the flight.

They have refused to cancel my flight. They are arguing that the change in the flight is less than 2 hours  and they cannot cancel the flight for free of cost. So what are options I have in this case?  Is there is any EU law which disclaim the ryanair argument?

Comment: When's the flight?  EU rules only kick in if changes happen within a certain timeframe leading up to the flight.

Comment: The flight is in June!

Comment: That would put it well outside the EUs 2 week period for compensation or accommodation then - the airline is giving you significant notice and the change is less than 2 hours.

Comment: I am not looking for any compensation. I just want to cancel the tickets because I do not want to fly with new timing.

Answer (score 4):

Under [Regulation 261/2004](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:32004R0261), you're only entitled to a refund if the delay **exceeds five hours**:

> Article 6
>
> Delay
>
> 1. When an operating air carrier reasonably expects a flight to be delayed beyond its scheduled time of departure:
>
> …
>
> passengers shall be offered by the operating air carrier:
>
> …
>
> (iii) when the delay is at least five hours, the assistance specified in Article 8(1)(a).

(Article 8(1)(a) is a refund.)

Of course, the airline is free to offer other options on top of what the regulation requires to keep a customer happy, but IMHO it's pretty unlikely they would let you cancel for free just because of such a small change (comparable with ordinary operating delays).